# Venedig ist immer einen Besuch wert

Tags: grammatical-case

Why is Akkusative used with the word "einen Besuch" in the sentence:

> Venedig ist immer einen Besuch wert.

Comment: Eigentlich gab es mal die Vereinbarung, dass zwei inhaltlich gleiche Fragen nicht als Duplikate angesehen werden, wenn die eine auf Deutsch und die andere auf Englisch gestellt wurde. https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/if-the-same-question-is-asked-in-german-and-english-is-it-a-duplicate

Answer (score 5):

In this context, it's always accusative:

> Etwas (nominative) is etwas (accusative) wert.
>
> Venedig ist einen Besuch wert.
>
> Das ist (k)einen zweiten Blick wert.
>
> Sein Leben ist keinen Pfifferling mehr wert.

See meaning 2 of [wert sein](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wert#Bedeutung2) in the Duden.